# Converting NaN floats to other types in Parquet format

Tags: pandas, dask, pyarrow, fastparquet

I currently am processing a bunch of CSV files and transforming them into Parquet.  I use these with Hive and query the files directly.  I would like to switch over to Dask for my data processing.  My data I am reading has optional columns some of which are Boolean types.  I know Pandas does not support optional bool types at this time, but is there anyway to specify to either FastParquet or PyArrow what type I would like a field to be?  I am fine with the data being a float64 in my DF, but can't have it as such in my Parquet store due to existing files already being an optional Boolean Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using the `fastparquet` engine, and the following keyword argument

```
object_encoding={'bool_col': 'bool'}
```

Also, pandas *does* now allow boolean columns with nans as an extension type, but it is not yet exactly default. That should work directly.

Example

```
import fastparquet as fp
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 'nan']})
fp.write('out.parq', df, object_encoding={'a': 'bool'})
fp.write('out.parq', df.astype(float), object_encoding={'a': 'bool'})
```

Comment: Thank you, will give this a shot.

Comment: Hey, I'm running into an issue with this solution,  I am getting`TypeError: expected list of bytes` when I add that argument to `to_parquet`.  `testing` is a `float64` in `t_df`, but is actually an optional bool column.  The call being made is: `dd.to_parquet(t_df, location, engine='fastparquet', partition_on=['day', 'id'], compression='snappy', write_index=False, object_encoding={'testing': 'bool'})`  Any clue whats would be wrong?

Comment: As my example shows, seems to work with float column or object columns of int/None (whether the null value is nan or None)